# Can material that has no magnetic properties be magnetically aligned?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, magnetic-fields, charge

Can a strong magnetic field be applied to material that has no magnetic properties have a residual magnetic field show the same behavior of a magnet? Example: Could a stick be magnetized where would it would line up with a magnetic field like a compass?

Can a stick be used as a compass needle?

Comment: @ACuriousMind feel free to guide me or edit anything of mine you see fit. Thanks

Comment: Please edit, right now it is unclear whether you are referring to organic or unorganic matter. Also the relevancy of this is unclear, as you then just mention a non-ferromagnetic material in the second question. Please make your question more specific and clear.

Comment: @Gimli is this better?

Comment: There is still "organic material" in the title of the question and unfortunately poor grammar makes it harder to grasp what you are asking.

Comment: @Gimli I'm trying to make it easier to understand. Some of my questions were hastily written, and I am trying to improve on them now I'm back from suspension from low quality questions. Please feel free to edit anything you see of mine and I will be grateful and learn from the edits. Some of them were just bad.

Comment: I've deleted some comments that were answering the question and others that were old. Please keep in mind that comments are meant for requesting clarifications and suggesting improvements on their parent post, not for answering.

Answer (score 1):

All materials have magnetic properties of one sort or another.  A strong enough magnetic field will either induce a similar magnetic polarization (paramagnetic) in a given material, or induce an opposite magnetic polarization (diamagnetic).  [Here](http://www.physics.org/facts/frog-really.asp) is an article about levitating a frog by using its diamagnetic properties.  [This](http://www.physics.ucla.edu/marty/diamag/) is another article describing some fun demonstrations of the principle.

[This article](https://nationalmaglab.org/education/magnet-academy/watch-play/interactive/diamagnetism-and-paramagnetism) goes to greater depth, and answers your question:

> Paramagnetic materials characteristically align with and strengthen an
>   external magnetic field, while diamagnetic substances partially expel
>   an applied field and always align themselves so that they are
>   perpendicular to its lines of magnetic force.

The fact that a diamagnetic object aligns perpendicular to the applied magnetic field means that a stick in a strong diverging field will align perpendicular to a north-south line.  It won't tell you what direction is north. Maybe a more complicated diamagnetic structure (e.g., a T-shaped structure hinged at the T intersection) can point north *if* you're in the Northern hemisphere, but it would point south in the southern hemisphere, because it would actually be sensing the divergence of the magnetic field density rather than the field direction *per se*.

Comment: The suggestion by @my2cts is much simpler than my T-shaped stick suggestion.  It, too, would point opposite directions in the northern and southern hemispheres.

Answer (score 1):

Wood is diamagnetic, so will be repelled by a magnetic field. Its reaction to the Earth's magnetic field is negligibly weak. In a sufficiently strong magnetic field a perfectly symmetric, diamagnetic, elongated shape if constrained at one end will point away regardless of the field polarity. Wood is a therefore a very much unsuitable material for a compass needle.